# Integration of Game Loop + Physic Engine : when to delete objects?

Tags: c++, physics-engine

How to manage code around physic engine, when a game object should be deleted?

I will use a tiny game as an example:-

### 1st iteration of development

I have a very simple game with 1 character (Jumper) and many platforms.

The game loop is like this :-

```
system_jumper.update();     //game-logic
system_platform.update();   //game-logic
system_physic.update();     //This is the only place where physic object will be actually added/removed.
```

**system_physic.update()** executes everything as batch (for performance reason).

If game-logic wants to creates / remove some physic objects,
such commands will be cached - postponed to be executed in the **system_physic.update()**.

It is very good so far.

### 2nd iteration of development

I want to remove a platform in a certain time-step.

I added a new line just before the **system_physic.update()**, as followed:-

```
system_jumper.update();
system_platform.update();
if(timestep==10)system_platform.removeId( platformId );  //#
system_physic.update();     //the rigid body is deleted here
```

The **#**-line wishes to do 2 things.

- I. remove physic object of the platform        (the command is
  buffered)
- II. remove logical game object of the platform

At that **#**-line, I can't delete the platform (both physic & logic part) immediately,
... because when the deletion command is executed in **system_physic.update()**,
... the physic callback for "end-collision" for the platform will be called.

When the callback occurs, the physic engine accesses the corresponding game object (platform's logical part in this case).

Therefore, at **system_physic.update()**, the platform must not be deleted yet.

### My poor solution

As a result, I hack it a bit, like this:-

```
system_jumper.update();
system_platform.update();
system_platform.removeId___BUFFER_DELETE_PHYSIC( platformId); //[I] Hacking logic
system_physic.update();          //the rigid body is deleted here
system_platform.removeId___DELETE_LOGIC_NOW( platformId);  //[II] Logic delete
```

It works, but it is very ugly i.e. low maintainability.

[image]

### Question

- Is it common that game logic code ugly like this?
- Is the buffer command (for physics) a bad idea in the first place?
- How to professionally solve this maintainability problem?

  (Low maintainability because codes about deletion scatter around, I & II)

The real problem is more complex that this, but the root is the same as  question.
(I usually encapsulate the hack inside some systems.)

**P.S. This is an example of callback**, provided just in case:-
The Jumper has a counter of platform that it step on, to determine whether the jumper can jump.
It is implemented by physic callback (object start collide +=1, object end collide  -=1).

Comment: Is there some reason not to use smart pointers to handle this issue automatically?

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner   Do you mean smart_pointer(C) stored in B -> when B deleted, C will be deleted?    The difficulty of this solution is that C is a physic body, it has to be deleted only physic_engine.   However, the physic engine has to delete many C at once for performance reason.   In the older version, I did something similar to that (delete one by one).  Thank!

Comment: You could have two-ways callbacks (on marking B for deletion you could trigger C's delete query) and actually remove B on the next frame

Comment: I recommend you do all object deletion/addition *after* updating but *before* rendering, sort of like how Unity does it. You cache all deletion/instantiation calls to be executed after the physics engine updates but before the objects are rendered, so that the change does not interfere with the physics.